# why you can't enable a disable index?

Tags: sql-server, index

My textbook says:

***"The opposite of an ALTER INDEX … DISABLE isn’t
ENABLE; that doesn’t even exist. You must perform an ALTER INDEX … REBUILD."***

But when you rebuild a index, you make the index reconstruct from scratch, which takes a lot of effort for database engine behind the scene as it need to create index by checking every existing rows
Let's say I just disabled an index, and do a couple of select statements(no insert, update or delete, just select) to feel what the life will be without the index.
Shouldn't it be sensible to have a 'Enable' option just like a switch to be turn on, without reconstructing the index for all records?

Comment: *I just disabled an index, and do a couple of select statements* -- No you can't .. have you tried it ? [read my answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/41605/8783)  that will help clear some misconceptions.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your sub-questions:

- If you disable the index, I presume the server will no longer maintain it.
- You mention that if you've performed some selects, and made no updates, you should be able to just re-enable it
- However how often would this actually happen? How often would there be a use-case requiring an index to be disabled, then re-enabled without any data updates? If the number of times this happens is infinitessimally small, then why would MS develop code that lets the server maintain a record of "have there been any data updates since the index was disabled... just in case the admin wants to re-enable it again, so we can dodge a rebuild?"

Seems sensible to me - once you've disabled it, assume it is useless and require it to be rebuilt if you want to use it again.

Comment: I have a use case, a bad one.  Big query that for some reason uses the index when it's sub-optimal.  Instead of tuning the query or using hints in the query, they disable the index it wants to use, forcing the query plan to use the correct (more optimal) index instead.    Like i said, it's terrible but someone, somewhere tried it, I'm sure.    But as you say, that's not the intended use case for disabling an index.

Comment: In your usecase you should force the query to use diffrent index (maybe clustered): [force-index-query-hints-index-hint](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/02/07/sql-server-introduction-to-force-index-query-hints-index-hint/)

Answer (score 0):

Recently I faced a problem where the number of DML statements were running on an audit database and stuck to complete. After analysis, we found that the index size on the table was half of the size of the table and creating a problem. After confirmation from the application team, we disabled it and rebuild after the process completion.

Microsoft has given the disable feature on index just to keep the metadata (index structure) and remove index leaf & non-leaf level pages. To let better understand I created an example to help you.

```
  create table test ( id int identity(1,1), name char(200) ) 
  go 
  insert into test(name)
  select 'test'
  go 2000

 CREATE INDEX [IX_NAME] ON test(name)
 go
 [![enter image description here][1]][1]

when you execute disable command on an index then sql server removes references of that index from sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats, sys.dm_db_Index_operational_stats DMV's. Checking from index properties displays no information on fragmentation as well.
```

alter index ix_name on test disable

[image]